# How to exclude some results of itertools permution by condition?

Tags: python, permutation

I'm trying to solve the problem from the Rosalind.

> Return: The total number of signed permutations of length n, followed by a list of 
>   all such permutations (you may list the signed permutations in any order).

I have an idea for a solution in Python, but I cannot implement it to the end. Consider for example that n = 2.

```
    numbers = [1, -1, 2, -2]
    ordering = permutations(numbers,n)
```

So now I've got some tuples as a result:

> (1, -1) (1, 2) (1, -2) (-1, 1) (-1, 2) (-1, -2) (2, 1) (2, -1) (2, -2) (-2, 1) 
>   (-2, -1) (-2, 2)

I need to exclude those that have elements of equal modulus. For example, (-1, 1). Is it possible to implement this, and if possible, how?

Answer (score 2):

A *pythonic* solution using list comprehension:

```
filtered_perms = [(x,y) for x,y in ordering if abs(x) != abs(y)]
```

Edit:
Code that works fine with python 3.7:

```
import itertools as itt

# create permutation generator object
perms = itt.permutations([-2, -1, 1, 2], 2)  

# here generator is turned into a list with certain permutations excluded
filtered_perms = [(x,y) for x,y in perms if abs(x) != abs(y)]

# print whole list
print(filtered_perms) 

# print first permutation
print(filtered_perms[0])

# print length of the list
print(len(filtered_perms))
```

Edit2:
To fix the problem with no elements in `ordering`:

```
ordering = list(itertools.permutations([-2, -1, 1, 2],2))
```

after that, ordering will be a list of all elements from `itertools.permutations`.

Comment: That looks like correct solution for me. But it just isn't working. When I call for _filtered_perms_ variable after executing this line of code I'm getting empty list in the output. I suppose that's also has something to do with the type of variable that itertools.permutation returns.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I **call** for filtered_perms"? `filtered_perms` is a list, which is *subscriptable* (`filtered_perms[0]`), not *callable* (`filtered_perms(0)`). 
If you want to access an element of `filtered_perms`, use square brackets.

Comment: Also: I suggest to update your post with more of your code because I believe something might be wrong in another piece of code.

Comment: Yeah, `filtered_perms` is a list but we are trying to create it from `ordering` which is not a list and I think that it causing all of the difficulties. In fact, there are almost all the code in my post , except for importing libraries and input variables. [1st part](https://pp.userapi.com/c850432/v850432472/14f4fd/jkDYYA8lpVc.jpg) [2nd part](https://pp.userapi.com/c850432/v850432472/14f507/ZX_-V3jV2wk.jpg)

Comment: Aha! The problem is that you `print(*ordering)` and **then** try to create `filtered_perms` which is wrong. `*ordering` causes to get all element of generator `ordering`. After it, `ordering` will be in a state when there is no value to *yield* from the generator anymore. See edit2 of my answer. Also, read about iterators and generators, it might be helpful in the future.

Comment: Yes, I often have problems with fundamental programming issues. I'm working on it. Is it okay to use something like `filtered_perms = [(x,y,z,a,b,c) for x,y,z,a,b,c in ordering if (abs(x) != abs(y)!= abs(z)!= abs(a)!= abs(b)!= abs(c))]` with bigger n (n=6 in this example)? I'm not sure that I am extrapolating this solution correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` function is probably what you're looking for.

```py
list(filter(lambda pair: abs(pair[0]) != abs(pair[1]), ordering))
```

The condition might be wrong, I'm not sure what you mean by *equal modulus*.

Comment: The problem is that result of the work of itertools.permutation is not exactly a list so calling to the items this way like pair[1] gives TypeError: 'itertools.permutations' object is not callable.

Comment: @michalwa:
`==` in the lambda should be changed to `!=` in order to **exlude** permutations of equal modulus.
@AnastasiiaZakarian
`itertools.permutation` returns a generator to be precise. Why and how do you call an `itertools.permutations` object?

Comment: @asikorski variable _ordering_ is a result of itertools.permutations. I am not very familiar with the way generators work, but, as I understood, I can't, for example, iterate over it in a for loop and print or change its elements this way. I used `print(*ordering, sep = " ")` to see what do I get as a result of its work but that's all what I came to.

Comment: @AnastasiiaZakarian I think what you should do is learn properly how the generators works. The problem you have is that you are doing `print(*ordering, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions proposed before are right, but if in the case that you want to process the resulting list after generating the permutations would be a nice idea to have a generator instead of a list. For that, I recommend you to design your own generator function based on `itertools.permutations`:

```
def signed_permutations(iterable, r=2):
    for item in permutations(iterable, r):
        if abs(item[0]) != abs(item[1]):
            yield item
```

And you can use it as:

```
for item in signed_permutations(numbers):
    do_something(item)
```

Or if you just want to create a list:

```
sigperm = list(signed_permutations(numbers))
```